# GRUB Boot Loader set timeout=0, how to get the boot menu?

Tags: grub2, opensuse, boot-loader

I run **GRUB** Boot-loader with open SUSE 13.2.

I set **timeout=0** at Boot-loader Options tab and Default Boot Section='Windows 7***'.

From then on, I couldn't see the GRUB menu to select which OS I want to boot

How do I get the boot menu back?

Comment: Have you tried pressing ESC key before windows starts to boot? Just after POST.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has solved your query. It'll be helpful for other with similar issues

Answer (score 4):

Try holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key just after `POST`

Answer (score 1):

If the above fails, it's quite easy (usually) to boot from any Linux live image (e.g., from a USB thumb drive), mount the /boot filesystem, and edit grub2/grub2.cfg on that to undo your change. For that you add

```bash
set timeout=10
```

to the very end of the file.

Do heed the warning at the beginning of the file, though — that file *will* get automatically overwritten, you will also have to change /etc/default/grub to undo the changes that led to timeout being 0. (But you can do that once you've normally booted your system).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with these:

1. In `etc/default/grub`, set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`
2. In the same file, set `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` to `hidden` or `countdown`. Don't set it to `menu` as it uses a different loop that is not interruptible.
3. In theory,pressing SHIFT before booting the system should interrupt the boot process and show the GRUB menu. In practice, on some EFI systems the SHIFT keypress is not relayed to GRUB due to how the underlying firmware works. In those cases, press SHIFT+non-ASCII character (e.g. SHIFT+F1) before the boot process to get to the GRUB menu.