# How to disable fast boot from Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, dual-boot

I have dual boot but accidentally turned on the fast boot option, so now I can't access Windows.

How can I disable fast boot from Linux or access boot menu since I'm not able to do either at the moment?

I did check some posts about it but didn't find much info on how to fix it. I'm using Windows 10 and Arch Linux.

I can't enter the BIOS settings because it's fast boot -- I have no way of accessing the boot menu.

Comment: You don't do this from the operating system, you need to do it in the BIOS/EFI settings. How you enter the BIOS depends on your computer and, again, is not affected by your operating system in any way. There is usually a button to press while the machine is booting (often `F2` or `Del`). Does that not work?

Comment: Are you talking about Windows [Fast boot](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001762.htm) or a [zero timeout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219064/100397) for `grub`?

Comment: @roaima: Sounds like it's neither of those. Sounds like it's a _firmware-level_ "fast boot", which is very often confused with the identically-named Windows feature but nevertheless a completely different thing.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have UEFI firmware in native mode, as "fast boot" is an UEFI-specific feature and doesn't really work in BIOS boot mode.

##### Accessing the boot menu

It is not necessary to disable firmware "fast boot" if all you want is to reboot to another OS – you can choose another boot option from within the running OS, by setting the *BootNext* EFI variable using `efibootmgr --bootnext`:

```
# efibootmgr
 BootCurrent: 0002
 Boot0002* Arch Linux
 Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
# efibootmgr --bootnext 0003
# reboot
```

You can achieve the same on Windows using `bcdedit /enum firmware` to find the respective BCD entry ID and `bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} bootsequence LINUX_ID` to set BootNext.

Note that this is is a temporary, one-time change. To save your choice as the new default, you need to change *BootOrder* using `efibootmgr --bootorder`, or likewise set the `displayorder` property via bcdedit on Windows.

##### Accessing firmware settings

To access the firmware setup screen ("BIOS settings") where you can disable fast boot mode, set the *OsIndications* EFI variable using `systemctl reboot`:

```
# systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

or, if you do not use systemd (unfortunately efibootmgr on Linux does not yet have a convenient option for this):

```
# var=OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
# printf '\7\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0' > /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/$var
# reboot
```

The Windows equivalent is `shutdown /r /t 0 /fw` – or the menu item you get when Shift-clicking the "Start > Reboot" option.