# Opensuse: I accidentally changed grub_timeout to 0. How do I access the grub menu now?

Tags: grub2

as above.

- I tried pressing right SHIFT (holding it) OR ESC keys and no effect.
- Both GRUB_TIMEOUT AND GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT are set to 0.
- I booted into a Live USB and tried editing /boot/grub2/grub.cfg but it does not work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GRUB Boot Loader set timeout=0, how to get the boot menu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219061/grub-boot-loader-set-timeout-0-how-to-get-the-boot-menu)

Comment: why can't you just boot into your system and change it back and `update-grub` (or whatever you do in opensuse)